# Authenticating error with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, sudo, 14.04, authentication

<
Problem:
Just as I upgraded my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS. I couldn't pass keyring and bash authentication.
I can login in recovery mood for both root and my account, but that's not the case in the gnome.
Every time I login with sudo, the bash response: "Sorry, try again."
If I login in the terminal with su, it says: "Authentication failure"
even when I lock the desktop, I can't login in the gnome, while I can do that with ctr+alt+f1 in tty1.

I'm pretty sure from the keys, caps is off, num is on, my account is already added to sudoers file and so on.
help me in this, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. In order to keep the site format consistent, please post the solution as an answer. That way you may even get up-votes from people who find your solution helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was using special characters in my password. It seems there was problem with them. I chose a new password without special characters and the problem got fixed.